# Android dependency com.google.firebase:firebase-core different version for the compile (12.0.1) and runtime (11.4.2)

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, dependencies, google-play-services

this is my Project Gradle dependencies

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.2.0"
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
```

this is my App Gradle dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
```

Also i have change implementation to api ... the error still appears

Comment: have you tried updating your dependencies, your firebase libs seem pretty outdated. Also you google services one, we're in version 15.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add below dependency into app level gradle file ..

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your google lib version into the stable version. you are using an unstable version. Use following

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
```

and use this classpath

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

and remove the firebase classpath from the project

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you apply the google-services plugin?  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#introduction requires you apply it at the bottom of your app's build.gradle to avoid dependency collisions similar to the one you are describing.

You can also run `./gradlew :app:dependencies` to see if you have any dependency collisions which lead to multiple versions of firebase-core.