# firebase-core-15.0.1.pom doesn't exist

Tags: android, firebase

I want to use firebase:

```
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.0" 
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2" //<-- this
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0"
```

but I got this error:

```
Could not find play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/15.0.1/play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar
```

this url doesn't exist:

https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.pom?referrer

my gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
       jcenter ()
       maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
         google()
        jcenter ()
```

Comment: Please review this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328801/android-dependency-com-google-firebasefirebase-core-different-version-for-the-c/50330043

Comment: adding the `google()` repository once is fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade firebase dependencies to the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

check here for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android